# Android buttons width in proportion

Tags: android, layout

I need to place 3 buttons i one line./Using LinearLayout/.
Problem is when change text on button. Width changes because of "android:layout_width="wrap_content". I want to be sure thab buttons will ocupy screen width i 4:4:2 proportion. Clause 'wrap_content' brokes this, but I can not use exact size because I don't know device screen width in design time.

Anybody knows easy way to solve this without using code?

Comment: Use layout_weight=1 for all buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set their width to wrap_content. Set proportional weights instead:

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    layout_width = "match_parent"
    layout_height = "wrap_content" />

    <Button
        ....
        layout_width = "0dp"
        layout_height = "wrap_content"
        layout_weight = 2 />

    <Button
        ....
        layout_width = "0dp"
        layout_height = "wrap_content"
        layout_weight = 2 />

    <Button
        ....
        layout_width = "0dp"
        layout_height = "wrap_content"
        layout_weight = 1 />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This works fine in my phone. Still have to try with different device.

Comment: Great! It should share the space in other devices too.

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:weightSum="10"   //    SEE THIS IS 4+4+2 = 10
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="4"   // THIS    IS   4
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="4"   // THIS    IS   4
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="2"   // THIS    IS   2
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is exactly was I did. Because of button label - system resized my button and broked proportion.

Comment: If you sets width to 0dp then you have to give height fix.. Can you give Height Fix?

Comment: How you given the height? Doesn't it vary when size changes of text length?

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: when I set height="wrap_content" and added larger text then Button's size then Height of Button varies.

Answer (score 0):

should be
android:layout_weight="4dp"